# Cannot run .pl files from CGI-BIN

Tags: perl, permissions, centos, plesk, cgi-bin

I am trying to install a FileManager software written in perl, and as per it's instructions I have had to upload a series of files to the cgi-bin of the subdomain I wish to install it on on my server. The error message I receive is a 500 Internal Server error, and when I check the error_log on the domain name, the error simply states 'Premature end of script headers: *filename*'.

I thought this may just be an error with the software and so I uploaded a simple perl file, which should just ouput some html to the screen, I confirmed that this file was working in my local environment (windows 7 + xampp) - and then amended my path to perl comment at the top of the file to reflect the correct path on the server; After doing so I am still receiving the same 500 error code and premature end of script log.

This tells me that this is not an error with the file but something to do with my configuration settings - the odd thing is that if I run my simple 'HTML outputter' file on the command line of my server using PuTTy, I get the correct output.

This then made me think that it may be a permissions issue with the file, however after CHMOD'ing the cgi-bin and file to 777 for testing purposes, I am not so sure - the cgi-bin directory is owned by the FTP user that I used to upload the files with and is part of the PSASERV group, however I do not know much about permissions and so i'm not sure whether this is relevant.

The server I am trying to install the software to is CentOS linux distro, running PLESK 9.5.2, PERL, CGI and PHP support are all enabled in teh web hosting settings of the domain in PLESK.

Comment: Do you actually output any HTTP headers in your script? It would help if you included a simplified version of the script in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your input, sorry I forgot to mention that the #! points to the correct perl location on the server, and also that I did check for CRLF line endings

Comment: Is anything being written to the web server error log?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input to everyone that took an interest in this question, I managed to fix the issue eventually; I believe it's a Plesk permissions issue that to run a perl script from cgi-bin it's necessary for the directory and script to be a part of the group 'psacln', regardless of the script owner or the script being set to 777 or otherwise.